# Getting a 503 service unavailable error on shared hosting when I try to export over 100,000 records to excel using Laravel 7 live-wire data tables

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

Getting a 503 error on shared when I try to export over 100,000 records to excel on shared hosting using laravel live wire datatables, my localhost, on the other hand, is behaving well.
Find attached screenshots of my .user.ini on shared hosting which has similar values with my php.ini file on my localhost and the error screen:

[image: .user.ini file]

[image: 503 error screen]

Answer (score 0):

I ve been experiencing the same issue with hostgator. From what i read up this happens when cpu threshold limit is exceeded and the IIS tries to recycle the application pool or there are multiple frequent application crashes. So one suggestion is to request the hosting provider to disable rapid fail protection:

[check this out](https://support.managed.com/kb/a625/service-unavailable-recycle-an-iis-application-pool-isolate-potential-causes-an-application.aspx)